# How do I send data class as json in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, post, backend

I try to sign up as a user to a back-end that takes some values as String and then a class that is called profile with some Strings within the Profile class. So in short the back-end wants some strings and a class.

```
Map data = {
      'username': name,
      'email': email,
      'password1': password1,
      'password2': password2,
      'profile': Profile(countryIsoCode: country),
};
```

This is how I declare field for backend. And I want to declare countryIsoCode as: `'country_iso_code': country,'`

But this is not possible within the Profile. And the backend don't get the value for countryIsoCode but when I did: `'country_iso_code': country,'` outside the profile it worked but then the back-end does not get a 'profile' value.

In my class I have also this function, but I don't know is I need it.

```dart
Map toJson() => {
  'countryIsoCode': countryIsoCode,
};
```

Then I send body to backend.

`String body = jsonEncode(data);`

I expect either to make the object to jsonObject or declare 'countryIsoCode': countryIsoCode within Profile.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your the `toJson()` method on your profile object to convert it to a dictionary that in turn can be converted to a JSON string and sent to the backend.

It will look something like assuming that all the other variables like `name`, `email` etc. are strings.

```dart
var profile = Profile(countryIsoCode: country);

Map<string, dynamic> dataTransferObject = { 
  'username': name, 
  'email': email, 
  'password1': password1, 
  'password2': password2, 
  'profile': profile.toJson(), // Important to call toJson here
};

var json = jsonEncode(dataTransferObject); // jsonEncode from dart::convert
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, but now I have the problem still with the value country, but I think its only to use Serializable for it.

Comment: I can't upvote posts, need 15 reputation it says and I don't know when or how I get that.